# Error in libcrypto.a when make C code

Tags: c, linux, ssl, openssl, daemon

I'm trying to build a standalone server on Linux follow this instruction:
https://github.com/kazuho/h2o
But when I type "make h2o", I got an error:

```
    Linking C executable h2o
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `dlopen'
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `dlsym'
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `dlclose'
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x354): undefined reference to `dlsym'
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x3fb): undefined reference to `dlerror'
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_var':
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x474): undefined reference to `dlsym'
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x52e): undefined reference to `dlerror'
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x5a4): undefined reference to `dlopen'
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x612): undefined reference to `dlclose'
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x640): undefined reference to `dlerror'
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x6be): undefined reference to `dladdr'
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x721): undefined reference to `dlerror'
    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_unload':
    dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x77a): undefined reference to `dlclose'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[3]: *** [h2o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/h2o.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/h2o.dir/rule] Error 2
    make: *** [h2o] Error 2
```

anyone can tell me exactly how can I fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: linking in the dl lib may help. `-ldl` on the link line *after* `-lcrypto`

Comment: can you give more details to fix it?

Comment: Beyond what I just did, 'fraid not. You're not linking your platforms `dl` library. Thus no `dl` functions are resolved at link-time.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand what I'm going to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the final executable should be linked against the `dl` library. Although this is not required on all systems, it is a bug that should be fixed by upstream author of [h2o](https://github.com/kazuho/h2o).

If you're seeking for a quick&dirty fix, open the CMakeLists.txt file and replace the line:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(h2o ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${LIBYAML_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

with

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(h2o ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES} ${LIBYAML_LIBRARIES} pthread -ldl)
```